# Grid is not occupying full height of its div when used inside flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a `grid` (`.genTempGrid`)  inside a column `flexbox` (which, in turn, is also inside column `flexbox`). Strangely, the created `grid` is not occupying full height of its div, instead, its height is limited to its content.

My understanding is, no matter what, height of `grid` == height of the div on which its sitting. Pls correct me if I am wrong.

```css
.d-flex-column-last-child-flex-grow-1 {
      flex-grow: 1;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      /*height: 100%;*/
    }
    
.child-expand {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }

.genTempGrid {
            display: grid;
            height: 100%;
            grid-template-columns: 20% 60% 20%;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr;
            background-color: #f7f7f7;
        }
        
.border1 {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="d-flex-column-last-child-flex-grow-1" style="height: 50vh">
  <div class=" d-flex-column-last-child-flex-grow-1 child-expand">
    <div class="pl-3 genTempGrid pt-2 child-expand border1">
      <div class="border1">hi</div>
      <div>hi</div>
      <div>hi</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**Edit: I am not looking for workarounds. I am more interested to know the reason behind the current behavior.**

Comment: can you clarify me. do u want to make the div with the class name .border1 to fill the whole height of its parent div?

Comment: Yes. There are two div `.border1` (one on grid's div and another on grid item), both should have same height.

Comment: there's a way but it will break the grid display! are you okay with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the this line

```
.d-flex-column-last-child-flex-grow-1 {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
```

For a full explanation see: [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size) and [Fitting child into parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826555/fitting-child-into-parent)

This can be fixed by using the shorthand `flex:1` instead or applying a `min-(dimension): 0` which forces a recalculation overall.

```css
.d-flex-column-last-child-flex-grow-1 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child-expand {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.genTempGrid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 60% 20%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.border1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex-column-last-child-flex-grow-1" style="height: 50vh">
  <div class=" d-flex-column-last-child-flex-grow-1 child-expand">
    <div class="pl-3 genTempGrid pt-2 child-expand border1">
      <div class="border1">hi</div>
      <div>hi</div>
      <div>hi</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put height: -webkit-fill-available css styling. Hope this helps. Thanks.

```css
.d-flex-column-last-child-flex-grow-1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*height: 100%;*/
}

.child-expand {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.genTempGrid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 60% 20%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.border1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child-expand > .border1 >div {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex-column-last-child-flex-grow-1" style="height: 50vh">
  <div class=" d-flex-column-last-child-flex-grow-1 child-expand">
    <div class="pl-3 genTempGrid pt-2 child-expand border1">
      <div class="border1">hi</div>
      <div>hi</div>
      <div>hi</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well it because you didn't set the align-content to stretch on the child div. You can see full explanation of grid align-content css value here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#article-header-id-22

Comment: `align-content : stretch;` doesnt solve the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/dilp41195/4g7381se/3/

Comment: If you read the article i sent you carefully you would understand. But here is another updated fiddle to help you understand better. https://jsfiddle.net/4g7381se/5/

Comment: `-webkit-fill-available` causes a lot of overflow problems. As an example see this: https://jsfiddle.net/dilp41195/tk4xe0hj/1/ . Also your your updated filddle changes the problem itself. You remove the height on the first div.

Comment: I can see you still need a lot of brushing up in css. The updated fiddle already using the proper method of grid template and the height 100% wouldn't apply with the grid at all, that's why i commented it.
Here is another updated fiddle to probably helps you better: https://jsfiddle.net/4g7381se/7/

And for your statement '-webkit-fill-available causes a lot of overflow problems' I don't see it that way and didn't find any article about that flaws. And in your fiddle what cause it to overflow is because of your display flex without specifying the height. https://jsfiddle.net/tk4xe0hj/5/